# How to multiply selected columns from different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 pandas dataframes (similar to the below one). I have 2 lists `list ID_1 = ['sdf', 'sdfsdf', ...]` and `list ID_2 = ['kjdf', 'kldfjs', ...]`

```
Table1:
    ID_1    ID_2    Value
0   PUFPaY9 NdYWqAJ 0.002
1   Iu6AxdB qANhGcw 0.01
2   auESFwW jUEUNdw 0.2345
3   LWbYpca G3uZ_Rg 0.0835
4   8fApIAM mVHrayg 0.0295

Table2:
     ID_1    weight1 weight2 .....weightN
0   PUFPaY9     
1   Iu6AxdB     
2   auESFwW 
3   LWbYpca     

Table3:
    ID_2    weight1 weight2 .....weightN
0   PUFPaY9     
1   Iu6AxdB     
2   auESFwW     
3   LWbYpca
```

I want to have one dataframe which should be calculated like,

```
for each x ID_1 in list1:
    for each y ID_2 in list2:
        if x-y exist in Table1:
            temp_row = ( x[weights[i]].* y[weights[i]])
            # here i want one to one multiplication, x[weight1]*y[weight1] , x[weight2]*y[weight2]
            temp_row.append(value[x-y] in Table1)
            new_dataframe.append(temp_row)

return new_dataframe
```

The required new_dataframe should look like Table4:

```
Table4:
        weight1 weight2 weight3 .....weightN value
    0           
    1           
    2       
    3
```

What I am able to do now is:

`new_df = df[(df.ID_1.isin(list1)) & (df.ID_2.isin(list2))]`
using this I am getting all valid `ID_1` and `ID_2` combination and values. But I have no idea, how I can get the multiplication of weights form both datafames ( without looping for each `weight[i]`)?

Now task is easier, I can iterate over the `new_df` and `for each row in new_df`, I will find `weight[i to n] for ID_1 from table 2` and `weight[i to n] for ID_2 from table3`. Then I can append their `one-one multiplication` with `"value" from table1` to new `FINAL_DF`. But I don't want to loop and do, can we solve this using some smarter way?

Comment: Updated in the question. I am not sure if we have any options without using looping.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```
data = """\
ID_1
PUFPaY9     
aaaaaaa
Iu6AxdB     
auESFwW 
LWbYpca
"""
id1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

data = """\
ID_2   
PUFPaY9
Iu6AxdB
xxxxxxx
auESFwW
LWbYpca
"""
id2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

cols = ['weight{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,5)]
for c in cols:
    id1[c] = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(id1))
    id2[c] = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(id2))

id1.set_index('ID_1', inplace=True)
id2.set_index('ID_2', inplace=True)

df_mul = id1 * id2
```

Step by step:

```
In [215]: id1
Out[215]:
         weight1  weight2  weight3  weight4
ID_1
PUFPaY9        8        9        1        1
aaaaaaa        6        1        9        2
Iu6AxdB        8        4        8        5
auESFwW        9        3        4        2
LWbYpca        7        7        1        8

In [216]: id2
Out[216]:
         weight1  weight2  weight3  weight4
ID_2
PUFPaY9        6        5        5        1
Iu6AxdB        1        5        4        5
xxxxxxx        1        2        6        4
auESFwW        3        9        5        5
LWbYpca        3        3        6        7

In [217]: id1 * id2
Out[217]:
         weight1  weight2  weight3  weight4
Iu6AxdB      8.0     20.0     32.0     25.0
LWbYpca     21.0     21.0      6.0     56.0
PUFPaY9     48.0     45.0      5.0      1.0
aaaaaaa      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
auESFwW     27.0     27.0     20.0     10.0
xxxxxxx      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```